# Python "classobj" error

Tags: python

I have this code and I couldn't run it because i get this error:
"TypeError: 'classobj' object is not subscriptable"
and here is my code:

```
import cgi
import customerlib

form=cgi.FieldStorage

history = customerlib.find(form["f_name"].value,form["l_name"].value)


print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print """<html>
  <head>
    <title>Purchase history</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Purchase History</h1>"""

print "<p>you have a purchase history of:"
for i in history: "</p>"
   print"""  <body>
</html>"""
```

I have the customerlib file beside this file. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
form=cgi.FieldStorage
```

`FieldStorage` is a class, not an object. You need to instantiate it to create a `FieldStorage` object:

```
form=cgi.FieldStorage()
```

It is erroring on `form["f_name"]` because form is currently an alias for the class of `FieldStorage`, not an object of type `FieldStorage`. By instantiating it, it's doing what you think it should be doing.

Check out the [cgi module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html) for more detailed information on how to use the CGI module.